# Optional arguments in type bound subroutines in Fortran 2008

Tags: class, types, fortran, polymorphic-associations, gfortran

What is the best way to call the type-bound subroutine `seed_rng`?

The compilation command `gfortran -Wall mwe.f90` of the following code produces the warning

```
         subroutine seed_rng_sub ( self, checkOS, mySeed )
                                      1
Warning: Unused dummy argument ‘self’ at (1) [-Wunused-dummy-argument]
```

To the novitiate, this suggests removing the `self` argument in the subroutine definition (that is, using `subroutine seed_rng_sub ( checkOS, mySeed )`). However this produces the errors

```
             procedure, public :: seed_rng => seed_rng_sub
                     1
Error: Non-polymorphic passed-object dummy argument of ‘seed_rng_sub’ at (1)
```

and

```
             class ( randomNumber ), target :: self
                                                  1
Error: CLASS variable ‘self’ at (1) must be dummy, allocatable or pointer
```

Besides the stackoverflow "Questions that may already have your answer", we also read discussions at http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gcc.fortran/33604 and https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/fortran/2010-09/msg00221.html without success.

The main program:

```
include 'mod test.f90'

program mwe

use mTest
implicit none

type ( randomNumber ) :: rnumber

    call rnumber % seed_rng ( .true. )

end program mew
```

The module:

```
module mTest

use iso_fortran_env, only: int64, real64

implicit none

type, public :: randomNumber

    real ( kind ( real64 ) ) :: x

    contains

        private

        ! subroutines
        procedure, public :: seed_rng => seed_rng_sub

end type randomNumber

private :: seed_rng_sub

contains

    subroutine seed_rng_sub ( self, checkOS, mySeed )

        use iso_fortran_env, only: int64

        class ( randomNumber ), target :: self

        integer, intent ( IN ), optional :: mySeed ( 1 : 12 )
        logical, intent ( IN ), optional :: checkOS

        integer :: n = 0
        integer, allocatable :: seed ( : )
        integer, parameter :: s0 ( 1 : 12 )  = [ 155719726,  156199294,  156319186,  156439078,  156678862,  156918646, &
                                                 157198394,  157318286,  157398214,  157438178,  157518106,  157877782  ]

            call random_seed ( size = n )
            allocate ( seed ( n ) )

            if ( present ( mySeed ) ) then
                call random_seed ( put = mySeed )
                return
            end if

            present_checkOS: if ( present ( checkOS ) ) then
                if ( checkOS ) then
                    call random_seed ( put = s0 )
                    return
                else
                    exit present_checkOS
                end if
            end if present_checkOS

            call random_seed ( put = s0 )

    end subroutine seed_rng_sub

end module mTest
```

Comment: The very first warning is just a warning. If it is bogus, just ignore it! I use `-Wno-unused-dummy-argument` to ignore them automatically, they are just a nuisance.

Comment: The compiler warning pointed to a void in my understanding which @casey was able to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, you have two options for calling this function -- with or the passed-object dummy argument.

In the version you have,

```
... 
procedure, public :: seed_rng => seed_rng_sub
...
subroutine seed_rng_sub ( self, checkOS, mySeed )
...
  class ( randomNumber ), target :: self
...
```

You will get the warning you see for not using `self`.  If you want to avoid the warning you can instead not pass the passed-object, changing the first two lines above and deleting the third:

```
...
procedure, nopass, public :: seed_rng => seed_rng_sub
...
subroutine seed_rng_sub (checkOS, mySeed )
...
```

The `nopass` attribute to the procedure tells Fortran not to pass the passed-object dummy argument, so you can remove it from the subroutine declaration and remove the variable from that subroutine.  The reason you got an error when you tried to change the subroutine is that without the `nopass` attribute, you were still specifying the procedures first argument was the passed-object dummy argument and your procedure didn't match.  See cl. 4.5.4.5 Fortran 2008 for further reading.

Comment: The explanation is very helpful. Thanks.